# accessing HP QC's OTA using servlet or any web apps to get the list of defects

Tags: java, linux, jsp, servlets, portal

I am in the middle of creating a support portal that will be displaying all the defects for some filter in HP QC.

I can see many examples using JAVA-COM bridge to access the OTA. I just want to know is there any method to develop an web app portal to display the Qc Defects and deploy in a Linux server or a Windows local machine to access it.